# split & showing value in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

i have one variable in javascript named itemid i.e. var  itemid=document.getElementById('item_code').value;

in item_code there is value in this format "1025*1" and i want to display only 1025 not whole in javascript div

plz give me some idea, it is same as explode() in php but i want this in javascript to display in div

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [`split` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

For example:

```
var array = value.split('*');
var first = array[0];
```

Alternatively,

```
var first = value.substring(0, value.indexOf('*'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) - Parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix or base.

> If parseInt encounters a character that is not a numeral in the specified radix, it ignores it and all succeeding characters and returns the integer value parsed up to that point. parseInt truncates numbers to integer values. Leading and trailing spaces are allowed.

Example:

```
parseInt("1025*1", 10); // 1025
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the spli method:

```
var itemid=document.getElementById('item_code').value.split("*")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

This will display "1025" (will strip *1) into DIV with ID="DIV_ID":

```
document.getElementById('DIV_ID').innerHTML = itemid.split(/(\d+)\*\d+/)[1];
```